# How do you copy RTF attachments into a new mailitem?

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

I am working with C# Outlook Object Model (with a little bit of C++ extended MAPI for decoding TNEF for RTF mails) and am trying to find a way to get the attachments from a mail I have used the tnef decode on (I opened this mail as a shareditem to access its contents), and add these attachments into a new mailitem. What I am observing with these attachments is that they either contain a filename with *"UTF8 Hex: xxxx.msg"* for message attachments, or shows `null` for `attachment.filename`, and the display name shows *"UTF8 Hex: xxxx"*. I know these attachments without filename are pdf/docx files since I attached them myself for testing, but there's no way to identify that from the hex encoded displayname and null filename.
*(Where xxxx represents a long string of hexadecimals)*

My usual go to when attaching HTML attachments when I am doing this is to use the `attachment.FileName` and do a `attachment.SaveAsFile(filename)`, then doing a `newmailitem.Attachments.Add(savedfile)` but with the filename not found in the attachment and the displayname not showing anything helpful, I am lost on how I should do the same for RTF mails.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean you are dealing with embedded OLE object attachments of type ATTACH_OLE?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am dealing with. I found out that the addin that wrapped the mail encoded the attachment components in Hexadecimals, so after I decoded it, I could get the actual filename for the msg files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no file names for the embedded OLE attachments. They are not even files, they are `IStorage` objects. You can extract the the file data from the streams inside the `IStorage` object.

Is there a particular reason why you are parsing the TNEF data explicitly instead of using [OpenTnefStreamEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/opentnefstreamex)?

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) is an option, is version of [RDOAttachment](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAttachment.htm).`SaveAsFile` extracts attachment data from the `IStorage` object under the hood.
Also note that you don't need to deal with attachments etc. if you want to copy the whole message into another message - you can call [RDOMail](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOMail.htm).`CopyTo()` and pass another object as a  parameter.